# Draw Lines and Circle in a Neat & Clean Way With Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I am absolutely new in `Circuitikz` package. I have to draw the circuit as shown below (Fig. 1).

[image: Original Circuit]

```
                                      Fig. 1: Original Circuit
```

With the help of internet, I was able to draw the required circuit somehow, as shown in the following image (Fig. 2).

[image]

```
                                      Fig. 2: My Drawn Circuit
```

Here is the code I used to draw the Fig. 2.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{
logic ports=ieee
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} [line width=1pt]

\node[and port](and_1) at (3,0) {\footnotesize AND 1};
\node[and port](and_2) at (3,-4) {\footnotesize AND 2};
\node[not port, rotate=-90](not_1) at (1,-2) {\tiny NOT};
\node[or port](or_1) at (6,-2) {\footnotesize OR};

\node[left, xshift=-60pt] at (and_1.in 1) (x1) {$x_1$};
\node[left, xshift=-60pt] at (and_1.in 2) (x2) {$x_2$};
\node[left, xshift=-60pt] at (and_2.in 2) (x3) {$x_3$};
\node[right] at (or_1.out) {$f$};

\draw (x1) -- (and_1.in 1);
\draw (x2) -- (and_1.in 2);
\draw (x3) -- (and_2.in 2);
\draw (1, -0.3) -- (not_1.in);
\draw (not_1.out) -- ++(0, -0.85) -- (and_2.in 1);
\draw (and_1.out) |- (or_1.in 1);
\draw (and_2.out) |- (or_1.in 2);

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Although, the drawn diagram is okay and acceptable, however, I am not fully satisfied with this. Below, I have noted the questions regarding the logic circuit as follows:

1. Like `Point 1` in Fig. 1, how can draw the bubble at `Point 2` of Fig. 2? I have tried with `\draw (1, -0.3) o- (not_1.in);` with no luck. Rather it shows some additional errors and does not render the line.
2. How to draw hollow circle at `Point 3`, `Point 4`, `Point 5` and `Point 6` in Fig. 2?
3. Is there any way to label a `\draw ;` command which we can call later on, as we can do with `\node[] (node_label){};` command? For example, in Fig. 2, I have labeled **AND 1** node using `(and_1)` and I have called it in places like `\draw (x1) -- (and_1.in 1);` and `\draw (and_1.out) |- (or_1.in 1);`.
4. If you notice, to place the NOT gate on top of **AND 1** gate's *2nd input* line and **AND 2** gate's *1st input* line, I had to hard-code the drawing position like `\draw (1, -0.3) -- (not_1.in);` and `\draw (not_1.out) -- ++(0, -0.85) -- (and_2.in 1);`. Now my question is, is there any better approach to achieve this (in a more robust and automated way) so that the not gate is placed in the middle of **AND 1** gate's *2nd input* line and so on?

Comment: Line endings (like arrows) are defined as options after the command like `\draw` or `\node`.  So my guess to question 1 is that `\draw[o-] (1,-0.3) — (not_1.in);`  would result in an open ended line at the starting point.

Comment: @alchemist after adding `\draw[o-] (1,-0.3) -- (not_1.in);`, it produces the hollow circle below the AND 1 gate's 2nd input line, not on top of it as shown in Fig. 1.

Comment: You should never use `[o-]` as a global `draw` option. They are thought to be used only in path-style component, that is, in `to[...]` specifications. @alchemist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, welcome!

You can position poles (that is the name of the "connection dots" or "open dots") wherever you want with `\node[circ] at (coordinate){}` (or `ocirc` for open ones). But the way you build your circuit makes identifying the coordinates difficult.

For example, you are positioning a node `(x1)` and then draw from the node --- notice that the line will start from the node *boundary*, not from the exact coordinate. I would draw from the port this way:

```
\draw (and_1.in 1) -- ++(-60pt,0) coordinate(x1) node[left]{$x_1$};
```

and now you can use the `short` bipoles instead of `--` to add a pole:

```
\draw (and_1.in 1) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x1) node[left]{$x_1$};
```

Now, the position where you have the black dot is the coordinate which is horizontally at the same level of `x2` and vertically on `not_1.in`; this is Ti*k*Z is written as `(x2 -| not_1.in)`.

So:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [line width=1pt]

    \node[and port](and_1) at (3,0) {\footnotesize AND 1};
    \node[and port](and_2) at (3,-4) {\footnotesize AND 2};
    \node[not port, rotate=-90](not_1) at (1,-2) {\tiny NOT};
    \node[or port](or_1) at (6,-2) {\footnotesize OR};

    \draw (and_1.in 1) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x1) node[left]{$x_1$};
    \draw (and_1.in 2) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x2) node[left]{$x_2$};
    \draw (and_2.in 2) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x3) node[left]{$x_3$};

    \node[ocirc] at (or_1.out) {};
    \node[right] at (or_1.out) {$f$};

    \draw (x2 -| not_1.in) to[short, *-] (not_1.in);
    \draw (not_1.out) |- (and_2.in 1);
    \draw (and_1.out) |- (or_1.in 1);
    \draw (and_2.out) |- (or_1.in 2);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The line width creates horrible antialiasing effects on okular, sorry...)

For your point 4, you can use an `inline not`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [line width=1pt]

    \node[and port](and_1) at (3,0) {\footnotesize AND 1};
    \node[and port](and_2) at (3,-4) {\footnotesize AND 2};
    \node[or port](or_1) at (6,-2) {\footnotesize OR};

    \draw (and_1.in 1) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x1) node[left]{$x_1$};
    \draw (and_1.in 2) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x2) node[left]{$x_2$};
    \draw (and_2.in 2) to[short, -o] ++ (-60pt, 0) coordinate(x3) node[left]{$x_3$};

    \node[ocirc] at (or_1.out) {};
    \node[right] at (or_1.out) {$f$};

    \draw (x2) ++(1,0) coordinate(tmp) to[inline not={\tiny NOT}, *-] (tmp |-and_2.in 1) -- (and_2.in 1);

    \draw (and_1.out) |- (or_1.in 1);
    \draw (and_2.out) |- (or_1.in 2);

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

You can also compute the midway coordinate between say `c1` and `c2` with the expression `($(c1)!0.5!(c2)$)`...

Comment: @pixel_boy I forgot that you could add text easily to the `inline not` (...which is fun, because I was the one who wrote it...). Edited!

Answer (score 8):

By using relative coordinates and `inline port`. For exercise only (since it is hard to compete with package author answer (+1) ;-):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[font=\scriptsize,
                   node distance=4mm,
                   ]
\draw   (0,0)   coordinate[label=left:$x_2$] (in_2)
                to[short, o-*] ++ (1,0)   coordinate (aux-1)
                -- ++ (0.5,0)   node[and port, anchor=in 2] (and_1) {AND 1}
        (in_2 |- and_1.in 1)    node[left]  {$x_1$}
                to[short, o-] (and_1.in 1)
%
        (aux-1) to[inline not=NOT, component text=left, name=not]  ++ (0,-3) 
                -- ++ (0.5,0)   node[and port, anchor=in 1] (and_2) {AND 2}
        (and_2.in 2) to[short, -o]  (and_2.in 2 -| in_2) 
                     node[left]  {$x_3$};
\node[or port, right=of not -| and_1.out] (or) {OR};
\draw   (or.out)  to[short, -o] ++ (0.5,0) node[right] {$f$}
        (and_1.out) |- (or.in 1)
        (and_2.out) |- (or.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant, yes (+1). I went for the minimum changes from OP; your solution is clearly better overall ;-).

Comment: @Rmano, thank you very much for king words (and upvoting)! I like exploring the options of this great package has to offer.